# What does the Recycling Box do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

In the shop in Greed Mode there is a Recycling box that you can donate coins into. What does it do?
I put some in but didn't notice any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Restock Box.](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Machines#Restock_Box) Blowing them up or putting enough coins in the rerolls all the items in the shop. They can also spawn in item rooms, where they will reroll the item.